# how to update a field after insert in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `Purchaseforms` with some fields. This table has two fields `PurchaseId` which is an identity and `PurchaseNumber` which is an `nvarchar`.

After inserting a row in Purchaseform table, it returns `@@IDENTITY`. I want to update the PurchaseNumber field after insert immediately.

E.g.

If the `PurchaseId` is 1000, `PurchaseNumber` should be updated to `P1000`. How can I do it?

Comment: You could use a trigger to update the field whenever an `insert` occurs.  Within the trigger you would use `inserted.PurchaseId`.  In other code I would suggest using `Scope_Identity()` or an `OUTPUT` clause.  `@@IDENTITY` has some issues that may result in surprises.

Comment: Could you please explain me more with an example.

Answer (score 0):

An insert trigger can be used to update one field based on another.

Note that the following code will always overwrite `PurchaseNumber`, even if a value was supplied when the row was inserted.  A `WHERE` clause could be added to the `UPDATE` skip rows that already have a value for `PurchaseNumber`.

```
create trigger PurchaseForms_Insert on PurchaseForms after Insert as
  begin
  set nocount on

  update PF
    set PurchaseNumber = N'P' + cast( i.PurchaseId as NVarChar(10) )
    from PurchaseForms as PF inner join
      inserted as i on i.PurchaseId = PF.PurchaseId
  end
```

Aside on triggers: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then please add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0):

can use better computed column

```
CREATE TABLE Purchaseforms
 (
  PurchaseId int IDENTITY,
  PurchaseNumber AS 'P' + CAST(PurchaseId AS nvarchar(10)),
  ... 
  other columns
  )
```